# Itunes Info Button Missing?

Tags: iphone, itunes, contacts

I am running the most current iTunes  11.14 version and am trying to sync my contacts on my computer to my iPhone 4s.

From everything that I have read, I'm told to find the "info" button and select from my choices.

For some odd reason, my version of iTunes does not have or show the "info" button next to Summary and Apps, etc.

Where is that little critter and if it's not on this version, how do I sync my contacts from my Mac to my phone?

Answer (score 1):

Apple removed support for syncing of contacts with iTunes 11. To synchronize contacts between a Mac and an iOS device you now *must* use iCloud.